# Cache problems with Varnish and FBOauth module

Tags: 7, users, proxies, social-network

I'm troubleshooting a problem with Facebook (FB) login on my site using the [Facebook OAuth module](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth).

Reproduction steps:

1. Be logged out of Facebook and my site
2. Log into my site using Facebook login button
3. Log out of my site (using site logout link). I'm still logged into FB
4. Use FB login button on my site to log in

I expected to end up at the home page logged in. Instead, I get redirected to the home page, but a cached version of it (so it appears I'm not logged in). Refreshing the browser causes the home page to reload logged in and I'm set from here.

The issue is the home page is being loaded from cache, but I'm not sure why. The site runs Drupal 7, Varnish, and the 7.x-1.5 version of the Facebook OAuth module.

Here are the headers from the initial FB login button click. Since I'm already logged into Facebook I'm redirected right away back to my site (this is expected).

```
Request URL:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=407390309287595&redirect_uri=http%3A//www.zujava.com/fboauth/connect&scope=email%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_website
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:c_user=3413203; csm=2; datr=bq8bT_JILi0PrW8H9GZ5BMy6; fr=0MYU2YYrkDuegxlUi.AWVgxOkdsHe9zhvPJdDW7h70n48; lu=RgWtdyxDRmUr6dOIqyRyPhtg; s=Aa45lsbBS4F1Oll2.BQBsO2; xs=67%3AuZMhOYBden1YIw%3A2%3A1342620598; p=5; act=1342620710713%2F3%3A0; presence=EM342620710EuserFA23413203A2EstateFDutF0EsndF1EnotF0Et2F_5b_5dEuct2F134262011B0Elm2FnullEtrFnullEtwF2196532340EatF1342620710745Esb2F0CEchFDp_5f3413203F1CC; locale=en_US
Host:www.facebook.com
Referer:http://www.zujava.com/user/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
client_id:407390309287595
redirect_uri:http://www.zujava.com/fboauth/connect
scope:email,user_about_me,user_website

Response Headers
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:18:46 GMT
Expires:Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location:http://www.zujava.com/fboauth/connect?code=AQBbeDeOf-cd6HCy6GALaDqESzcfgTJNmh_i5iIx2IpG-KOWBTJHcylhigo82ZGR_X2SOJVzkwcvIKa7rD4dxcg2CLLDa3eZJMkDlP6D3UIU6c-iCFu_TZg6LkfLM4cOGKtu5HraaQUrLUPJd96hOsmpDuW9lzTLuBeMH4fwI7m7p3Jybig1GE06098OJCGuGos#_=_
P3P:CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:locale=en_US; expires=Wed, 25-Jul-2012 14:18:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-FB-Debug:GPh2t018FPktnIalVO4RrxjZAQ3onlvvFyAEgI6g08U=
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:0
```

Next are the headers that complete the FB login on my site's side. You can see the session cookie being created in the response headers:

```
Request URL:http://www.zujava.com/fboauth/connect?code=AQBbeDeOf-cd6HCy6GALaDqESzcfgTJNmh_i5iIx2IpG-KOWBTJHcylhigo82ZGR_X2SOJVzkwcvIKa7rD4dxcg2CLLDa3eZJMkDlP6D3UIU6c-iCFu_TZg6LkfLM4cOGKtu5HraaQUrLUPJd96hOsmpDuW9lzTLuBeMH4fwI7m7p3Jybig1GE06098OJCGuGos#_=_
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ctools-collapsible-state=views-ui-advanced-column-petting_zu_graduates%3A1%2Cviews-ui-advanced-column-newly_published_content%3A1%2Cviews-ui-advanced-column-test%3A1%2Cviews-ui-advanced-column-html_sitemap%3A1; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; __atuvc=31%7C25%2C4%7C26%2C0%7C27%2C5%7C28%2C5%7C29; has_js=1; __utma=249598093.1349651830.1327187978.1342578105.1342618991.600; __utmb=249598093.64.9.1342621126771; __utmc=249598093; __utmz=249598093.1341848548.567.26.utmcsr=facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/l.php
Host:www.zujava.com
Referer:http://www.zujava.com/user/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
code:AQBbeDeOf-cd6HCy6GALaDqESzcfgTJNmh_i5iIx2IpG-KOWBTJHcylhigo82ZGR_X2SOJVzkwcvIKa7rD4dxcg2CLLDa3eZJMkDlP6D3UIU6c-iCFu_TZg6LkfLM4cOGKtu5HraaQUrLUPJd96hOsmpDuW9lzTLuBeMH4fwI7m7p3Jybig1GE06098OJCGuGos
URL fragment
#:_=_

Response Headers
Age:0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:18:47 GMT
Location:http://www.zujava.com/
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Pantheon-Edge-Server:10.183.199.123
X-Varnish:181771624
cache-control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
content-type:text/html
etag:"1342621126"
expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
last-modified:Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:18:46 +0000
server:nginx/1.0.15
set-cookie:SESS650d63be2a9c0113cd1740e78b8184ed=961WQoY1iwAJSjEBiuglfI_TDsz3VA8BReyLK2wnz44; expires=Fri, 10-Aug-2012 17:52:07 GMT; path=/; domain=.zujava.com; HttpOnly
x-drupal-cache:MISS
```

The final home page request:

```
Request URL:http://www.zujava.com/#_=_
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
URL fragment
#:_=_
```

I believe this indicates the home page is being loaded by the local browser cache, and no request is actually being made to the server. If so, I'm confused as to why. I assume the problem would be in how I'm telling browsers to cache the home page?

Here are the response headers for a logged out page load of the home page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-drupal-cache: HIT
Etag: "1342622308-0"
Content-Language: en
x-generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:38:28 +0000
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 8686
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2012 14:50:55 GMT
X-Varnish: 658648930 658583362
Age: 295
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Pantheon-Edge-Server: 10.183.199.163
```

Any hints or ideas would be welcome.

Comment: 1.  Does this work if you fully bypass Varnish?  2.  I think you will get a better response on ServerFault.  I don't think this is loading from local cache; the response would have either not happened or you would have seen a request with If-Modified-Since.

Comment: 1. It works on my loca copy that doesn't use Varnish and has the same code. 2. I posted to ServerFault. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

we ran in the same issue during regular login/registration and have implemented a javascript "hack" to:

- on login set “user” cookie (session only)
- on all anonymous pages include a javascript that will check for the “user” cookie.
- if a cookie is found then a logged in user is on a cached page. Force reload of the page with javascript.
- on logout clear the “user” cookie.

The code is available here: 
http://drupal.org/sandbox/clivelinsell/1751804

You can read more of the history about it [here](http://help.getpantheon.com/pantheon/topics/cached_page_served_for_logged_in_user).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the link to Pantheon thread. This is exactly our issue. I will take a look.